# I want to compine these two bsdf perfectly the first one including diffuse of the orange text, the second one is for metal wear

Tags: shaders

as you can see I want to merge these too perfectly

[image: Text]

Comment: Hello it's not clear what you mean by combine, maybe elaborate a bit?

Comment: i mean mixing, i want to mix these too, my English is bad sorry ;(

Answer (score 1):

You can use a black and white image as mask between the 2 materials (plug it in the *Factor* input of the *Mix Shader*), you'll need to unwrap and scale and move your UVs so that the text is correctly placed:

[image]

Comment: yeah, I figured it out,i used the same text texture and made a mask out of it, thanks!